# javascript views and subviews design pattern

Tags: javascript, oop, view

I'm wondering how best to handle views and subviews using a Javascript OOP approach. Here's the basic task: I want to create a horizontal, swipe-able list of panes. The swipe element itself will be a view, and within it I will have many subviews -- one for each pane. My current approach looks something like this:

```
function Swipe(el){
  this.el = el;
  var els = el.querySelectorAll('li');
  this.subviews = els.map(function(li){
    return new Pane(li);
  }, this);
}

Swipe.prototype.goto = function(num){
  // alter this.el to show the current pane, based
  // on index. 
}

function Pane(el){
  this.el = el;
}

Pane.prototype.bind = function(){
  // bind click events
}
```

This design pattern works decently well for me, but **what is the best way to access the parent view from the subview**? I've gone so far as to pass `this` when constructing the subview, like this:

```
this.subviews = els.map(function(li){
  return new Pane(li, this);
}, this);

function Pane(el, parent){
 this.el = el;
 this.parent = parent;
}
```

And this allows me to call functions from the parent view -- for example, I could use the `goto` function in response to a subview button being clicked. But I'm guessing that this isn't really optimal.

So my question: **what is the best way to handle views and subviews, specifically the ability of subviews to call functions from their parent views?**

Comment: Your approach sounds good enough to me. Another possibility is having the Swipe instance listen to events triggered by its Pane instances. But since both classes inherently depend on each other, passing `this` is a good solution. That's my opinion.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. i had also considered having the views emit events, and have the Swipe view listen for them... but simply passing `this` seemed to be the easiest. Glad to know I'm not missing something obviously better.